# StompClient Android fails to connect with SpringBoot server giving error "Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '"

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, stomp

I am using the below library for StompClient implementation on my Android native code:

[StompClient Library](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid)

It connects to the same URL with "HTTP" but when I use "HTTPS" mapping it doesn't connect and throws the below exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.Exception: java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '
```

Here is my code:

```
private var stompClient: StompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, STOMP_URL)

stompClient.connect()

disposable = stompClient.topic("/rooms/roomId")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ topicMessage ->
            Log.d("LiveChatStomp", "Message ${topicMessage.payload}")
        }, {
            Log.d("LiveChatStomp", "Exception occurred: ${it}")
            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have HTTPS enabled in your springboot config? That requires extra steps, such as generating a valid certificate and loading it onto local devices.

By the way, 4XX is an HTTP client error. You might be requesting an HTTPS endpoint that is not configured, thus, the client request is the error.

Comment: HTTPS is enabled. In fact, the connection is working from the web panel side. It is only the Android side that is facing the issue. Could you please guide me on how to load the certificate in our local devices?

Comment: @Prabhat Try using [this guide](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/212869927-How-do-I-install-Securly-SSL-certificate-on-Android-device-). Let me know if it works, and if not, we can troubleshoot some more.

Comment: still not working. Getting the same error as before even after installing the certificate.

Comment: @Prabhat Are you using SockJS in your Spring bean? According to your library, `At now library works only as client for backend with support STOMP, such as NodeJS (stompjs or other) or Spring Boot (SockJS).` If not, enable it with `registry.addEndpoint("/example-endpoint").withSockJS()` in `registerStompEndpoints` bean.

Comment: I am using .withSockJS() in my endpoints. I can connect to HTTP/WS urls. It is only the HTTPS/WSS that is giving the error.